# How to extract the text when scraping p tags and br tags

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an issue with scrapping using Beautiful Soup. I want the text from:

```
url_example = 'https://www.verychic.fr/p/21/brunelleschi-hotel-s'
```

Which should be:

```
<p data-v-7816a06c="" class="product-location">
      Piazza Santa Elisabetta 3<br data-v-7816a06c="">
      50 122<br data-v-7816a06c="">
      Florence<br data-v-7816a06c="">
      Italie
    </p>
```

However, when I try to use this code:

```
address  = (soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'product-location'})).text
```

I have the following response/error from Python:

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How do I avoid NoneType when scraping using Beautiful Soup and `<br>` HTML tags?

Comment: What does soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'product-location'}) return?

Comment: This code `address  = (soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'product-location'}).text` can't work because there are unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: I forgot about it  :)  but still the same responses

Comment: Please show us a sample program that you are using, not just a single line of code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
address  = soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'product-location'}).text
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.